# shifted keyboard shortcuts not working after 12.1 upgrade

Tags: keyboard

Ever since upgrading to *Mathematica* 12.1, the keyboard shortcuts that involve the shift key -- such as control-^ (control-shift-6) for a superscript, and control-@ (control-shift-2) for a square root -- don't work. Instead, I just get a beep, and the "Why the beep?" menu command produces the explanation "You used a Command or Control key combination that is not defined to do anything."

I inspected the contents of `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/Macintosh/KeyEventTranslations.tr`, and the shortcuts that aren't working still seem to be listed. The file contains, for example,

```
    Item[KeyEvent["6", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["Keypad6", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["^", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Superscript"],
```

and

```
    Item[KeyEvent["2", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Radical"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["Keypad2", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Radical"], 
    Item[KeyEvent["@", Modifiers -> {Control}], "Radical"],
```

so I have no idea what might have broken.

I'm using macOS 10.15.3 (Catalina) on a Macbook Pro.

I rely on the shifted versions (control-shift-6 instead of control-6, etc.) because at the OS level I use control-(number) shortcuts to change desktop spaces.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It hurts just to type those ctrl-shift-number combinations, but I can confirm the difference between Mathematica v12.0 and v12.1 on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: :) Thanks. (It’s not so bad once they get into muscle memory.)

Comment: I didn't even know they worked with the shift key pressed down.  I've always done it without shift.

Comment: Just a weird thing.. I have Mathematica 12.1 on OSX 10.15 and after commenting out the commands you mention, like KeyEvent["2" and KeyEvent["6", they still work. It looks like Mathematica is not using only that system file for shortcuts, but loading sth else. I used (* *) like other commented lines in that file, so I wouldn't expect them to work. It's strange. Also, adding new shortcuts works with KernelExecute[..], but FrontEndExecute[..] does not work. Have you solved your problem yet?

Comment: @Vladimir No solution yet. It’s a pain.

Comment: Have you been editing that file, like adding new shortcuts, modifying anything present?

Comment: @Vladimir Not before the troubles… I messed with it a tiny bit in an attempt to figure out why the shifted versions were no longer working, by commenting out existing things and/or adding in new copies of the existing ones, but with no effect. I'm pretty sure the problems began with the 12.1 upgrade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some shortcuts in `KeyEventTranslations.tr` started making problems with new macOS + new Mathematica.

The "non shifted" shortcuts still works only because they are also defined in `MenuSetup.tr`. So, you can find it and change it there. The two files are in the same directory.

Find

```
MenuItem["Superscript", "Superscript", MenuKey["6", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

change to

```
MenuItem["Superscript", "Superscript", MenuKey["6", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]],
```

and

```
MenuItem["Radical", "Radical", MenuKey["2", Modifiers->{"Control"}]],
```

change to

```
MenuItem["Radical", "Radical", MenuKey["2", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]],
```

Comment: It works!! (In the process of verifying that, I discovered that the original problem does not affect my desktop iMac, only my Macbook Pro -- even though both are running the same versions of MacOS and Mathematica. In general, I've got them configured pretty darn close to identically. Odd.)

Comment: Wow! It is even more mysterious than [I thought](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221619/how-to-control-global-key-event-handling-for-all-front-end-sessions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a collision between the Mathematica shortcut and the Mac OS level shortcut for Mission Control, which is ^6 means "Switch to Desktop 6".  I don't use these Mission Control shortcuts, so I just unselected them in System Preferences, under Keyboard\Mission Control.  (I unselected ^1 through ^6.)

Subscript with ^6 and Radical with ^2 then work on Mathematica again.

I'm using Mathematica 12.1 on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.15.5.

Comment: I do use the Mission Control shortcuts — frequently and reflexively — which is why I need Mathematica's shift-control versions to work, and why I noticed when they stopped working.