# Entering inline math not possible

Tags: user-interface

I just noticed a problem when I tried to input an inline math cell, via "ctrl+(" this gives an unexpected beep but it is not starting inline math. Works fine in Mathematica 12.0 but not in Mathematica 12.1. I use MacOS 10.15.5.

Update: In the writing assistant's palette it is also wrong:

[image]

Anyone else with this problem, or is it only me?

Comment: It seems that a number of shortcuts were broken in 12.1: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219137/shifted-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working-after-12-1-upgrade

Comment: @MassDefect: No longer sure wether something is broken or thins are simply changed, from "ctrl"+"(" and "ctrl"+")" to "ctrl"+"9"....